# Dispute on a now-deleted question

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

A question was closed/delted because of a dispute?

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. For more info visit meta.

With:

> this question has been deleted as a result of a moderator flag. The flag is being reviewed, and the question may (or may not) be undeleted later, or completely destroyed too, depending on the result of the review

I have not seen a dispute like this before (and it said to look at meta).
What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

The author of the question posted code that he shouldn't have (i.e. wasn't authorized to), then asked to have it taken down.

We *really* don't like to delete questions with answers, especially upvoted answers.  I've upvoted some of your other answers as compensation.

Comment: Really? compensation? I upvote his other answers because they are good... ;-)

Comment: @rolfl I don't normally troll through a user's history to serial-vote. Be assured, though, that I'm still skimming/reading Loki's answers.

Comment: As much as I agree about a little compensation, I think it's mainly his *time* that was wasted.  Hopefully the OP will still benefit from it in some way.

Comment: PS. I don't care that much about the votes. Feel free not to bother with the free votes on other questions for me.

Comment: @LokiAstari It's just an uncomfortable situation for everyone involved: trouble for the OP, wasted time for you, and discomfort for the moderators for deleting a post we didn't really want to. A few additional upvotes would be therapeutic, and good for the site anyway.

Answer (score 3):

That's the post notice that's always shown with content dispute locks.  If there's not already a Meta post about it, then it likely means that the site moderators are discussing the post amongst themselves or with other users in private.

Regarding this particular request, the OP has flagged the post for deletion.  Although it *has* already been deleted, the other moderators and I may decide to undelete it and work out something different.